# Newbee Working with Classes and Dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, class

Newbee Working with Classes and Dataframes. I have an error I cant resolve. Thank You !

```
class Plot_Data:

    def __init__(self,PlotDataDF,Plotname,DateTime,FieldAngle,LP):
        self.PlotDataDF = PlotDataDF 
        self.Plotname = Plotname
        self.DateTime = DateTime
        self.FieldAngle = FieldAngle
        self.LP = LP
DataPoint = pd.DataFrame()
Try = Plot_Data(DataPoint,"","",-1,-1)
list = []
list.append ( Try(DataPoint,"","",-1,-1) )
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 list.append ( Try(DataPoint,"","",-1,-1) )

TypeError: 'Plot_Data' object is not callable

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) 
 ... **list = []** - you really shouldn't use built-in names for your variables.

Comment: `Try` is an instance of `Plot_Data`. `Plot_Data` does not have a `__call__` method so you cannot call it.

Comment: Would you mind showing me good format/code of this? Thank You

Comment: It isn't clear what your intent is. Did you mean `a = []; a.append(Try)`?

Comment: I am trying to make a array of 'Plot_Data' objects that I can populate as i read datasheets. I think the dataframes are preventing me from doing so.

Comment: also how do you grey your words?

Comment: `a = []; a.append(Try)` ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210446/discussion-between-chas-777-and-wwii).